# How to integrate a link in a slider round checkbox

Tags: html, forms, checkbox

I have a checkbox in my html page.

```
  <label class="switch pull-left">
       <input type="checkbox" checked="">
       <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
```

I want to create an action when the check box is unchecked.Is it possible to make a link inside a checkbox. I have only this much contents. If i put the whole href like

```
<a href="somelink.html">link</a>
```

The link word will be displayed. But i dont want such a word. Please help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to display a link *only* when the checkbox is unchecked. If that is the case, you can structure the HTML this way:

```
<label class="switch pull-left">
   <input type="checkbox" checked="">
   <span class="slider round"></span>
   <a href="somelink.html">link</a>
</label>
```

then add this CSS that prevents the a tag from displaying when the checkbox is checked:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ a
{
    display: none;
}
```

That should about do it.

Comment: not like that. it should go to a page (say an action for changing the status) if the checkbox is either checked or not

Comment: So you want the link to activate when the user checks/unchecks the checkbox? May I ask why? Seems like you're doing more work than you need to here.